# Workaround for lack of look-behind for Javascript regex

Tags: javascript, regex, python-3.x

I have a working Python regex statement as:

```
regex = re.compile(r"(?<=(==))(.*)(?=(==))")    
myList = regex.findall(contents)
```

For context, the input string may resemble (for example):

```
== Test User ==
Comment here

== Test User 2 ==
Comment here
```

And I wish to extract the username, and the related comment on the line below.

I want to use this regex in my Javascript program, however Javascript lacks look-behind functionality.

Is there a suitable workaround for this?

Comment: Doesn't the Python solution yield a tuple of `('==', 'some value', '==')`? Do you need to replicate that?

Comment: You're absolutely correct @WiktorStribiżew, but I don't need to replicate this exact behaviour, just be-able to detect the username and comment.

Comment: It means your initial solution did not work for you, right? See [`==\s*(.*?)\s*==\s*([\s\S]*?)(?=\n==|$)`](https://regex101.com/r/6NQgM7/1) that captures both types of information.

Answer (score 1):

The standard way is to match both the lookbehind and the desired data and use capturing groups to do what you want :

- if it is to retrieve the data, then put it in a capturing group you will consult after each match
- if it is to transform the data, you will want to have at least the "lookbehind" in a capturing group so you can reproduce it in the output, and maybe the desired data if you need to refer to it.

Examples :

```
# in these examples, we look for "overflow" preceded by "stack"
"stackoverflow".match(/stack(.*)/)[1]                // -> overflow
"stackoverflow".replace(/(stack).*/, "$1underflow")  // -> stackunderflow
"stackoverflow".replace(/(stack)(.*)/,"$2ed $1")     // -> overflowed stack
```

Another problem that we encounter with JavaScript's regex implementation is that `String.prototype.match`'s behaviour is inconsistent : it will generally return an object akin to an array of captured groups, however if your regex specifies the `g`lobal flag it will instead return an array of (string) matches, and the details of the capturing groups will be lost.

To work around this, you can use the `Pattern.prototype.exec` method instead :

```js
var pattern = /==\s*([^=]+)/g;
var input = `== Test User ==
Comment here

== Test User 2 ==
Comment here`;
while (match = pattern.exec(input)) {
    console.log(match[1]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not need any lookbehind here, even in Python you could get rid of it and use the following expression with `re.findall` (just remove `/` and `/gm` and compile with `re.M` flag):

```
/^==\s*(.*?)\s*==\s*(.*(?:\r?\n(?!\r?\n).*)*)/gm
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/qE1LdM/1).

**Details**:

- `^` - start of string
- `==\s*` - two `=` symbols and then 0+ whitespaces
- `(.*?)` - Group 1 capturing any 0+ chars other than line break chars as few as possible up to the first occurrence of the subsequent subpatterns
- `\s*==\s*` - two `=`s enclosed with 0+ whitespaces
- `(.*(?:\r?\n(?!\r?\n).*)*)`  - Group 2 capturing

  - `.*` - the rest of the line
  - `(?:\r?\n(?!\r?\n).*)*`  - zero or more sequences of

    - `\r?\n(?!\r?\n)` - a CRLF or LF (line break) not followed with LF or CRLF (another line break)
    - `.*`  - any 0+ chars other than line break chars (the whole line).

JS demo:

```js
var s = `== Test User ==
Comment here, one line only

== Test User 2 ==
Comment here
with line 2`;
var rx = /^==\s*(.*?)\s*==\s*(.*(?:\r?\n(?!\r?\n).*)*)/gm;
var results = [], m;
while(m=rx.exec(s)) {
  console.log("--- New match found ---");
  console.log("User:", m[1]);
  console.log("Comment:", m[2]);
}
```